# Create multiple elements with CSS generated content?

Tags: css

I have a div (blue in the image below). I need to create a number of equally spaced circles within it. Can this be done with CSS generated content? I could create 2 with the :before and :after pseudo classes, but as I need more would a CSS solution requite more html elements?

I was hoping to not have to use an image to improve loading times and to optimize the site for different display density devices.

[image]

UPDATE This is for a responsive design so the width of the blue div will vary. They also need to remain equally spaced.

Comment: You're better off using a repeating background image that uses SVG, and falls back to PNG for browsers that don't support SVG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, we could create only two pseudo-elements for each element.

However, we could fake the effect by multiple `box-shadow` values, as follows:

```css
.box:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: orange;

    box-shadow: 25px 0 0 0 orange,  /* Or use positive offsets if needed */
               -25px 0 0 0 orange,
                50px 0 0 0 orange,
               -50px 0 0 0 orange;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/KE6SY/)**.

### Update

Unfortunately, it's not possible to set a `box-shadow` offset relative to the *width* of the containing block. *([The best try](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/KE6SY/2/) would be using relative `em`/`rem` units, but the `font-size` itself can not be changed per the width of the container)*

Therefore, using `radial-gradient` background is the best option you'd have (as [@Michal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2957910/michal-brasna) has suggested).

In order to keep the aspect ratio of the blue box, you could set the `height` to `0` and use a percentage value for `padding-top` which relies on the width of the containing box.

```css
.box {
  background: orange radial-gradient(closest-side, transparent 40%, skyblue 0%);
  background-size: 20% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;         /* Make sure that the box has no height */
  padding-top: 20%;  /* Keep 5:1 aspect ratio                */
}
```

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/C5m3h/)**.

Comment: This is for a responsive design so the width of the blue div will vary and I need the background images to be equally spaced. If I try and change the box shadow position from px to a % value it seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use [radial-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient).

```
.circles {
  /* red: color of the circles */
  background-color: red;
  /* 40%: size of circles proportionally to size of an element they reside in */
  /* blue: color of the background */
  background-image: radial-gradient(closest-side, transparent 40%, blue 0%);
  /* 20%: width of circle, so 5 in row */
  /* 100%: height of circle, so 1 in column */
  background-size: 20% 100%;

  /* 20%: keep the aspect ration 5:1 for dynamic layout */
  padding-bottom: 20%; /* or padding-top */
  /* 100%: fill up given space */
  width: 100%;
  /* 0: so the possible content doesn't distort the aspect ratio */
  height: 0;
}
```

**Demo on http://jsfiddle.net/Gobie/t6X3Z/3/**

Comment: Will this solution work for a responsive design? The width of the blue div will vary. When I do this to your fiddle the circles get elongated into ovals.

Comment: Updated, and it is just as @HashemQolami wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If you place several nested `div`s inside your container `div` you can use `border-radius` to create the circles. Something like this should do the trick:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/GXL3w/

Comment: I was hoping to achieve this without adding new html elements.